# Integer $2n^2+2$ as the sum of 2,3,4, and 5 squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

> If $n-1$ and $n+1$ are both primes, establish that the integer $2n^2+2$ can be represented as the sum of 2, 3, 4, and 5 squares.

I managed to solve 2 and 4 squares, since:
$$2n^2+2 = (n+1)^2+(1-n)^2= n^2+n^2+1^2+1^2.$$

For 3 squares I thought the following. I do know that a positive integer can be represented as the sum of 3 squares if it is not of the form $4^n(8m+7)$. Since $n$ is even, $2n^2+2$ can be written as $8k^2+2$, which is not of the form $4^n(8m+7)$, so it can be represented as a sum of three squares.

Now I only need to prove the 5 squares part, but I don't know where to start. Any hints? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Typically we allow 0^2 in the representation. If you were able to do this with 2 squares, then add 0^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 at the end.

Comment: Formally, the problem should be posed.  $$x^2+y^2+z^2+r^2=2n^2+2$$   Or in a similar form.  This means we need to solve the Diophantine equation of some sort.

Comment: An easier way to do the three squares part is to note that one of $n+1$ and $n-1$ is of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: Can you write $2n^2$ as sum of three squares?

Comment: If $n-1$ and $n+1$ are both prime then $n=4$ or $n$ is divisible by $6$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $2n^2=4^{-1}(8n^2)$ (am I allowed to do that?) so it should be representable as a sum of three squares. But this is impossible to write in terms of $n$ right? So let $2n^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$, then $2n^2+2=a^2+b^2+c^2+1^2+1^2$.

Comment: An extension of Lagrange's for square theorem states that any positive integer above 17 can be expressed as a sum of 5 positive squares.

Comment: @rah4927 I know that $n+1$ and $n-1$ are of the form $4k+1$ and $4k+3$, but I don't see how that helps. Could you give another hint?

Comment: @user95864, any prime of the form $4k+1$ is representable as a sum of two squares. Suppose $n+1$ is of this form. Then $2n^2+2=(n+1)^2+(n-1)^2=(x^2+y^2)^2+(n-1)^2=(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2+(n-1)^2$. The other case is absolutely similar. Btw, Mark Bennet's comment is extremely useful in resolving the five squares part.

Comment: @rah4927 This is nicer than what I had, thanks!

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks a lot! I managed to solve the problem with your hint!